# Unexpected number of Hibernate sessions created in a multi EAR context

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, ear, jta

We are facing an issue when using Spring JTA + Hibernate in a multiple EAR context.

We have multiple transactional services (using @Transactional).
Our services are POJOs that have a reference to a DAO.
We also have multiple persistence units. For sake of simplicity, lets assume that each service/dao uses a distinct PU.

If Service1 in EAR1 starts a transaction and calls service2 in EAR2 multiple times then :

- Calls to Service2 will create a new hibernate session per call.
- All the sessions will be flushed/committed at the end of the transactions (i.e. when the Service1 calls is done and commits the transaction). -

Important note : Spring and Hibernate are not loaded by the root classloader, but by the EAR classloaders. 
This implies that Spring and Hibernate classes are loaded once per EAR.

Looking into the code and debugging led us to believe that the issue comes from thread local synchronization (i.e. the TransactionSynchronizationManager class).
What happens is:

- A transaction is started by Service1 in EAR1
- Service1 calls Service2 in EAR2
- Because Service2 is also transacted the TransactionAspectSupport kicks in around the Service2 method that is being called.
- Down the road the EntityManagerFactoryUtils will check if an EntityManager is registered with TransactionSynchronizationManager. This happens when SharedEntityManagerCreator calls    EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(). See call stack 1 below.
- Because no EntityManager is registered, it will create a new EntityManager and a new Hibernate Session. See call stack 2 below.
- When returning from the Service2 call, the synchronization is removed because it is considered as a new one. This happens in    TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(). See call stack 3 below.
- Subsequent calls to Service2 will go through the process of creating a new entity manager + session + synchronization again.

Because all the sessions are also registered with the global transaction, they all get flushed/committed at the end of said transaction.
A side effect, is that if the calls to Service2 modify the same entity, then that entity gets stored multiple times to the RDBMS (i.e. multiple identical update queries are fired).

The same scenario with both Service1 and Service2 deployed in the same EAR yields completely different results:

- Only one hibernate session is created
- That unique session is flushed at the end of the transaction (and a single update query is fired)

In some of our scenarios, we are seeing hundreds of sessions being created over a short period of time and this is causing performance issues.

It is possible that moving Spring and Hibernate to the root ClassLoader could fix the issue but it does not feel right.
What if the the two EARs are deployed in separate JVMs ?
Moving spring and hibernate up in the ClassLoader hierarchy  would also badly break our spring context setup...

Is this the expected behavior of Spring Transactions ? 
Is it possible to avoid the thread local synchronization and use transaction synchronization ?
Is our setup (see below) wrong with regard to what we are trying to achieve ?

We are using :
Spring version : 3.2.8.RELEASE
Hibernate version : 4.1.12.Final

Here are some relevant fragments of our Spring setup :

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        abstract="true">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="${jpa.database}" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="coreDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">${jpa.transaction.jta.platform}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets">${jpa.wrap_result_sets}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${jpa.generateStatistics}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${jpa.cache.factory_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${jpa.formatSql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${jpa.useSqlComments}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Where jpa.transaction.jta.platform = org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform

```
<bean id="referentialCoreEntityManagerFactory" parent="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/referential-core-persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="referential-core" />
</bean>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="referential-core" transaction-type="JTA" />

</persistence>
```

Base class of our DAOs showing how the entity managers are defined:

```
public abstract class BaseDAO<E extends IBaseEntity> extends com.sungard.decalog.framework.domain.dao.jpa.BaseDAO<E> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * @param entityClass
     */
    public <U extends E> BaseDAO(Class<U> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected final EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "referential-core")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

}
```

Call stack 1 : Creation of new EntityManager and Session:

```
Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 239 in SessionImpl)) 
->  SessionImpl.<init>(Connection, SessionFactoryImpl, SessionOwner, TransactionCoordinatorImpl, boolean, long, Interceptor, boolean, boolean, ConnectionReleaseMode, String) line: 239 
    SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession() line: 1597  
    EntityManagerImpl.getRawSession() line: 121 
    EntityManagerImpl.getSession() line: 97 
    EntityManagerImpl(AbstractEntityManagerImpl).joinTransaction(boolean) line: 1207    
    EntityManagerImpl(AbstractEntityManagerImpl).postInit() line: 178   
->  EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl, PersistenceContextType, PersistenceUnitTransactionType, boolean, Class, Map) line: 89    
    EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(Map) line: 179 
    EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager() line: 174    
    GeneratedMethodAccessor450.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available 
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean).invokeProxyMethod(Method, Object[]) line: 376  
    AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 519    
    $Proxy116.createEntityManager() line: not available 
->  EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory, Map) line: 202  
    SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 211  
    $Proxy118.find(Class, Object) line: not available   
    GenericLoaderCodifDAO(BaseDAO<E>).findById(Serializable) line: 57   
    GenericLoaderCodifService.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 18   
    ReferentialFacade.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 161  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 317 
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 183  
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 150  
    TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation() line: 96   
    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class, TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback) line: 260  
    TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 94    
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 204   
    $Proxy124.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available    
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_Impl(ReferentialFacadeBean).findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 271   
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Object, Object[], int) line: not available  
    SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(BaseRemoteObject, MethodDescriptor, Object[], int, String, Class<?>) line: 40 
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available  
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(int, Object[], Object) line: not available    
    ServerRequest.sendReceive() line: 174   
    ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(RemoteReference, RuntimeMethodDescriptor, Object[], Method) line: 345   
    ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(Remote, RuntimeMethodDescriptor, Object[], Method) line: 259    
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl_1036_WLStub.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    RmiClientInterceptorUtils.invokeRemoteMethod(MethodInvocation, Object) line: 116    
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor).doInvoke(MethodInvocation) line: 99    
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor).invokeInContext(MethodInvocation) line: 141  
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor).invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 189 
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 204   
    $Proxy314.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available    
    ReferentialService.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 54  
    SessionService.refreshSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData) line: 1114   
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 317 
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 198   
    $Proxy357.refreshSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData) line: not available   
    SessionFacadeService.loadSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData, ReloadSession) line: 880  
    SessionFacadeService.loadSession(long, ReloadSession) line: 848 
    ...
    <snip>
```

Call stack 2 : Registration of newly created EntityManager synchronization :

```
Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Suspended) 
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(TransactionSynchronization) line: 289 
    EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory, Map) line: 211  
    SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 211  
    $Proxy118.find(Class, Object) line: not available   
    GenericLoaderCodifDAO(BaseDAO<E>).findById(Serializable) line: 57   
    GenericLoaderCodifService.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 18   
    ReferentialFacade.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 161  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 317 
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 183  
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 150  
    TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation() line: 96   
    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class, TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback) line: 260  
    TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 94    
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 204   
    $Proxy124.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available    
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_Impl(ReferentialFacadeBean).findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 271   
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Object, Object[], int) line: not available  
    SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(BaseRemoteObject, MethodDescriptor, Object[], int, String, Class<?>) line: 40 
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available  
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(int, Object[], Object) line: not available    
    ServerRequest.sendReceive() line: 174   
    ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(RemoteReference, RuntimeMethodDescriptor, Object[], Method) line: 345   
    ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(Remote, RuntimeMethodDescriptor, Object[], Method) line: 259    
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl_1036_WLStub.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    RmiClientInterceptorUtils.invokeRemoteMethod(MethodInvocation, Object) line: 116    
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor).doInvoke(MethodInvocation) line: 99    
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor).invokeInContext(MethodInvocation) line: 141  
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor).invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 189 
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 204   
    $Proxy314.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available    
    ReferentialService.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 54  
    SessionService.refreshSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData) line: 1114   
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 317 
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 198   
    $Proxy357.refreshSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData) line: not available   
    SessionFacadeService.loadSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData, ReloadSession) line: 880  
    SessionFacadeService.loadSession(long, ReloadSession) line: 848 
    ...
    <snip>
```

Call stack 3 : Clearing of EntityManager synchronization (this will cause a new one to be created for each Service2 call) :

```
Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Suspended) 
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.clearSynchronization() line: 328  
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.clear() line: 464 
    WebLogicJtaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).cleanupAfterCompletion(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 1006   
    WebLogicJtaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 805 
    WebLogicJtaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).commit(TransactionStatus) line: 724   
    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport$TransactionInfo) line: 475    
    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class, TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback) line: 270  
    TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 94    
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 204   
    $Proxy124.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available    
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_Impl(ReferentialFacadeBean).findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 271   
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Object, Object[], int) line: not available  
    SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(BaseRemoteObject, MethodDescriptor, Object[], int, String, Class<?>) line: 40 
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available  
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(int, Object[], Object) line: not available    
    ServerRequest.sendReceive() line: 174   
    ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(RemoteReference, RuntimeMethodDescriptor, Object[], Method) line: 345   
    ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(Remote, RuntimeMethodDescriptor, Object[], Method) line: 259    
    ReferentialFacadeBean_590diy_EOImpl_1036_WLStub.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    RmiClientInterceptorUtils.invokeRemoteMethod(MethodInvocation, Object) line: 116    
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor).doInvoke(MethodInvocation) line: 99    
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor).invokeInContext(MethodInvocation) line: 141  
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor).invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 189 
    ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 204   
    $Proxy314.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: not available    
    ReferentialService.findGenericLoaderCodif(String, String, String) line: 54  
    SessionService.refreshSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData) line: 1114   
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
    AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 317 
    JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 198   
    $Proxy357.refreshSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData) line: not available   
    SessionFacadeService.loadSession(ISessionContext, ISessionSnapshot, ISessionData, ReloadSession) line: 880  
    SessionFacadeService.loadSession(long, ReloadSession) line: 848 
    ...
    <snip>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the architecture/design you've used sounds quite terrible. You mentioned 2 extremely bad practices (shared database and ownership of entities). Each EAR should own a domain (or groups of domains with their domain objects and db schema) and any other application (or EAR) shouldn't access that data directly and should only retrieve them through an API that the EAR owns and exposes. Please don't try to fix anything by moving jars around. Fix the architecture first.

Comment: My question was not about good or bad design or relevance of having one or more EARs. It was more about what I beleive is an issue in the way spring and hibernate handle JTA transactions spanning multiple EARs which, I fully understand, is one of the more complex use cases and should be avoided if possible. Point of the question is to find a solution *without* fixing the architecture as the cost of doing that is several orders of magnitude higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid the use of shared classloaders, this can give rise to all sorts of problems with static variables being shared accidentally between applications.

For example static loggers will be shared, so if you turn on trace debug in one application, you will see the other application slowdown as well, this is just an example of what the shared classloader can cause as unintended side effect.

Something similar could be happening not necessarily in Spring or Hibernate but in some transitive dependency that they use, most of these libraries are meant to be deployed at the application classloader level.

Currently there is no really good reason to put spring and hibernate at a shared classloader, they hardly consume any memory compared to other things.

I personally would put Spring and Hibernate in each WAR instead of moving it further down to the JVM, that would actually make the application un-redeployable, and would try to reduce the use of shared libraries to a minimum.

Also cross EAR calls usually are not needed, it's a programming model that is mostly abandoned due to complexity problems. The usual solution is to ship the service/DAO layer in a separate jar, and deploy the jar in the two applications. The application code can then call the service layer directly without the need for a call to another EAR.

The native transaction manager auto-detected by `tx:jta-transaction-manager` is then no longer needed and can be replaced by something like `JpaTransactionManager` or `HibernateTransactionManager`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. We actually have the two approaches in our product : same service+dao deployed in all ears and service+dao deployed in a single "shared" ear. Problem appears only with the former ;). That said, the current architecture is 14 years old... and we are waiting for the opportunity to simplify it and get rid of the multiple ears (but that the window of opportunity has not opened yet).